# Select the elements with at least one value in their data attribute, which is included in a certain array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am writing a filtering function, in which I need to select the elements that have a certain value in their data attribute, and those values are included in an array, allow me to explain it in an example:

For example, I have three elements and a button as follows:

```
<div data-foo="aa,cc,ff" ></div>
<div data-foo="bb,cc,ff" ></div>
<div data-foo="bb,dd,ee" ></div>

<div class="button" data-boo="aa,ff" ></div>
```

The data-foo in each element contains comma-separated values. When I click on the button, I create an array (*`myArray` in the code below*) from its data attribute, then I need to select those elements that at least one of the values in that `myArray` is in their data-foo, for a clear explanation please see the code below:

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {

     // First I make an array from the button's data attribute 
     var myArray = $(this).data('boo').split(',');


     // Select should be elements that their da-foo has at least one 
     // — of values in the array above
     var Select = "?"

});
```

How the `Select` variable can target the first two elements, since the first one has both "aa" and "ff",  and the second element has "ff".

I really tried to put it the way that makes sense, if it is not clear enough, please let me know and I will be happy to explain more, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    // First I make an array from the button's data attribute 
    var myArray = $(this).data('boo').split(',');

    // produces array of strings like '[data-foo*="aa"]'
    var selectors = myArray.map(function(value) {
        return '[data-foo*="' + value + '"]';
    });
    // searches by selectors joined by comma, returns all elements
    // that satisfy at least one selector
    var selectedElements = $(selectors.join(','));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this:

```js
$(".button").click(function() {

  // First I make an array from the button's data attribute 
  var myArray = $(this).data('boo').split(',');


  // Select should be elements that their da-foo has at least one 
  // — of values in the array above
  var Select = $("div[data-foo]"); //select all elements with data-foo
  Select.each(function(index, element) {
    var isInMyArray = $(element).data("foo").split(",").some(function(element) {

     if ( myArray.indexOf(element) != -1)
      {return true;}//if true then element is in myArray

    }); //using some here - if one value is found in array return true.
    console.log(isInMyArray);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-foo="aa,cc,ff"></div>
<div data-foo="bb,cc,ff"></div>
<div data-foo="bb,dd,ee"></div>

<div class="button" data-boo="aa,ff">test</div>
```